# Html 5 Download attribute in iPhone

Tags: angular, html, ionic2

I have a requirement where I need to download and view files( pdf, word, jpg etc) from the server in ionic progressive web app without navigating away from the page. What would be the best and easiest way to get it done ?

I have achieved this by using html5-Download attribute in android but its not working as expected in iPhone.

Any help would be great.

Regards
TA

Comment: Download attribute does not support version below 10.1

Comment: Yes, you are right. I can see document in iPhone6+ but there is no back button to go back to main application.

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN Web Docs, the [Download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) is not supported in Safari on iOS. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Browser_compatibility. There is also a requirement that the file to be downloaded is served from the same origin. I'm not familiar with Ionic 2 or Angular, however in regular HTML5 Web Apps, we have just used `target="_blank"` which downloads the file. If you need to stay on the same page, just use `target="_self"`.

Answer (score 0):

The upcoming release of iOS 13 will support the download attribute. The underlying [WebKit Bug #102914](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=102914) is now marked as `RESOLVED FIXED`.
[caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download) also lists the feature as supported in that version by now. Therefore, libraries like [file-saver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) are expected to just work in that version.

Comment: I'm on ios 13 beta - works (sort of) in safari but not in chrome :(